# ¿Cómo saber si un archivo existe en fish?

Tags: archivo, fish, exists

Supongamos que estoy en un directorio y quiero saber si un archivo con nombre `archivo` existe.

¿Cómo puedo comprobarlo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se puede resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
if test -e ./archivo
    echo "El archivo existe"
end
```

Extraído de [How to test for file or directory in Fish](http://codeyarns.com/2014/02/27/how-to-test-for-file-or-directory-in-fish/)